# Render Ajax question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

Excuse me, Perhaps it is a foolish question.

there is a way for render a view (with action include) inside other view through ajax request?

I need to use ajax but i need that data don´t charge in principal action. I need that data charge in other action.

I don´t want to use a partial.

Thanks in advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have an empty container `div` and fill it with the return data of a `jQuery.ajax` call to an action on one of your controllers with `render :viewname, :layout => false`